# Spring MVC @Valid annotation in contoller class causes glassfish server to throw an exception

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, glassfish

I have created SpringMVC project in netbeans 8.2. The contoller class is as shown:

```
@Controller
public class FormController {
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
binder.setAllowedFields(new String[] {
"userName", "password", "confirmPassword", "firstName",
"lastName", "email", "Marketing", "legalConfirmation","myAddress" });
}
@RequestMapping(value="new",method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleregistration(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("userdatabean",new UserDetails());
    return "Registration";

}
@RequestMapping(value="Registration",method=RequestMethod.POST)    
public ModelAndView Gatherdata(@Valid 

@ModelAttribute("userdatabean")UserDetails 

data,BindingResult error,ModelMap modelmap)throws Exception{
if(error.hasErrors()){
    ModelAndView modelerror=new ModelAndView("Registration");
    return modelerror;

}
ModelAndView dataModel=new ModelAndView("success");
dataModel.addObject("registration", data);
return dataModel;

}    


}
```

The Form registration is as shown below:

```
%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>User Registration</title>
    <style>
        .error{
            color: red; font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form action="Registration" modelAttribute="userdatabean" >
        <h1>New user Registration</h1>
        <div>UserName: <form:input path="userName"/>
            <form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error"/>
        </div>
        <div> Email: <form:input path="email"/>
            <form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/>
        </div>
        <div> Address:<form:input path="myAddress.StreetName"/>
            <form:errors path="myAddress.StreetName" cssClass="error"/>
        </div>
        <div> first Name: <form:input path="firstName"/>
            <form:errors path="firstName"  cssClass="error"/>
        </div>
        <div> Last Name: <form:input path="lastName"/>
            <form:errors path="lastName"  cssClass="error"/>
        </div>
        <div> Password:<form:password path="Password"/>
            <form:errors path="Password"  cssClass="error"/>
        </div>
        <div> Confirm Password:<form:password path="confirmPassword"/>
            <form:errors path="confirmPassword" cssClass="error"/>
        </div>
        <div><form:checkbox id="Marketing" path="Marketing"/>Please send  

me information via email
            <form:errors path="Marketing" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
        </div>
        <div><form:checkbox id="legalConfirmation" 

path="legalConfirmation"/>I accept the terms of use
                <form:errors path="legalConfirmation" cssClass="error"/>
            </div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Register"/></div>    
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The UserDetails Class

```
@Component                                                                  @ScriptAssert(lang="javascript",script="_this.confirmPassword.equals(_this.Password)",message="password mismatch")
public class UserDetails {
private String userName,Password,email,firstName,lastName,confirmPassword;
private Address myAddress;
private boolean legalConfirmation=false;
private boolean Marketing=true; 
@NotNull
@Size(min=2,max=20,message="Username has to be between 2-20")
public String getUserName(){
    return this.userName;
}
public void setUserName(String UserName){
    this.userName=UserName;   
}
@NotNull
@Size(min=8,max=100,message="password must be between 8-100")
public String getPassword(){
    return this.Password;
}
public void setPassword(String Password){
    this.Password=Password;
}
@Email(message="the email must be a real address")
public String getEmail(){
    return this.email;
}
public void setEmail(String Email){
    this.email=Email;
}
@NotNull
@Size(min=1,max=20,message="first name must be between 1-20")
public String getFirstName(){
    return this.firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName=firstName;
}
@NotNull
@Size(min=1,max=20,message="Last name can only be between 1-20")
public String getLastName(){
    return this.lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String LastName){
    this.lastName=LastName;
}
@NotNull
@Size(min=8,max=100,message="Confirm password must match password")
public String getConfirmPassword(){
    return this.confirmPassword;
}
public void setConfirmPassword(String Confirm){
    this.confirmPassword=Confirm;
}
public void setMarketing(boolean ok){
  this.Marketing=ok;  
}
public boolean getMarketing(){
    return this.Marketing;
}

public void setLegalConfirmation(boolean legal){
    this.legalConfirmation=legal;
}
 @AssertTrue(message="You must check the terms and conditions")
public boolean getLegalConfirmation(){
    return this.legalConfirmation;
}

public Address getMyAddress(){
    return this.myAddress;
}
public void setMyAddress(Address MyAddress){
    this.myAddress=MyAddress;
}   

}
```

the Success page is as follows:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Registration Successful</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>successful registration of user</h4>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Student Username:
            </td>
            <td>${registration.userName}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Student last name:
            </td>
            <td>${registration.lastName}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Student first name:
            </td>
            <td>${registration.firstName}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Student email:
            </td>
            <td>${registration.email}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Student address:
            </td>
            <td>${registration.myAddress.StreetName}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The [name]-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org

/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.Ricko.Controller"/>


 </beans>
```

The problem is when I add @Valid annotation to my Contoller class the Glassfish server throws an exception regardless of the input I enter;valid or not. without the @Valid annotation the code runs without any errors. I am using spring version 4.0.1.
The exception thrown is as shown below:
    Warning:StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for   servlet

```
 dispatcher threw exception
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at org.springframework.validation.
 AbstractErrors.isMatchingFieldError(AbstractErrors.java:236)
 at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.
 getFieldError(AbstractBindingResult.java:216)
 at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.
 SpringValidatorAdapter.processConstraintViolations
  (SpringValidatorAdapter.
 java:122)
 g.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.
 validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:108)
 g.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:760)
 at 
 org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor
 .validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:161)
  at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.
  ModelAttributeMethodProcessor
.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:109)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.
 HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument
 (HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.
 InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues
 (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.
 InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest
 (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.
ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle
 (ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.
 RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod
 (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.
RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal
(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.
AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.
doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.
doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.
processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost
(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.
service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service
(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.
doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.
doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.
internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.
doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.
invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.
invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.
doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.
invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.
invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.
invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.
doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.
service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.
ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.
service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.
runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.
doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.
handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.
execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.
executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.
executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.
execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.
process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.
execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.
fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.
fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.
run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.
access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at  org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.
WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.
run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.
doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.
run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The exception is not thrown when I enter the same legal arguments without the @Valid annotation. Inserting it back, it throws. Kindly assist to resolve it. I am learning the framework so may not be adept at it.

Comment: And you dump all your code but forget the important part the actual exception...

Comment: Message: Internal server error

Comment: description:The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

root cause java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: type Exception report

    messageInternal Server Error

    descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it   from fulfilling this request.

   exception

   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request  processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

root cause

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.

Comment: Please edit your question and format approprialty don't add as comments as that makes it unreadable.

Comment: what are "AbstractErrors.isMatchingFieldError" in spring validation?

Answer (score 0):

I have included the jars  validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar, hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-4.1.0.Final.jar by Right-click your project, choose "Properties"

Go to "Libraries", tab "Processor".